# Unable to subset the data from Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I tried to create a subset from Pandas dataframe based on some conditions. I was able to create two subsets, but get a syntax error when trying to create another subset.

The dataframe is .csv file with column headings: Number, Environment, Phase, Type, Planned end date, Closure code, Closure Subcategory, Incident Caused by Change, Pending Change. What code should I try to create a subset using "Planned end date" wherein the records which have Planned end date more than 4 days from today's date should be in a different subset? I'd like to create a different subset with all "Successful" and "FULLY SUCCESSFUL" records, and also a different subset with has null values for Incident Caused by Change and Pending Change.

Original dataframe:

[image: original dataframe]

Subset error:

[image: subset error]

No subset error:

[image: no subset error]

Comment: you can get subsets like this: `df.loc[:,['Successful','FULLY SUCCESSFUL']]`

Comment: Please fix the formatting of your post, and include the contents of those pictures as text. See: [mcve]. As for the error you’re getting: Use `df[‘col_name’]` instead of `df.col_name` to get columns. The latter has no upsides, only downsides.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the format `df2.Closure Subcategory == ...`, python uses only *Closure* as the column name, and assumes that everything after the space is another part of the statement. So when it sees the word "Subcategory" on its own after a `dataframe` column, it throws an error.

As @Alexander Cecile mentioned in the comment section, use the other method to call a column, e.g `df2['Closure Subcategory'] == ...`, and the subset would be created.

Comment: @Alexander Cecile, tried to follow the step you've mentioned. Now I got Key error. 
Code : - df4 = df3['Closure code' == 'Successful']     #did I execute the code correctly?

Comment: @Alexander Cecile, tried to follow the step you've mentioned. Now I got Key error. 
Code : - df4 = df3['Closure code' == 'Successful']     #did I execute the code correctly?
KeyError:- False

Comment: @vinaykumar No, you haven't. You need to close the "]" after the column name.

Comment: thanks it worked....also wanted after subsetting needed this to printed with all the other dimensions....it only gives the boolean dtype output. Can you guide please

Comment: @vinaykumar To get the complete rows of `df3` that fills the condition, you need to do `df4 = df3[df3['Closure code'] == 'Successful']`, that means *Give me all the rows in df3 where df3 in the column "Closure code" has the value "Successful"*

Comment: thank you @Aryerz it worked......what about my other question...What code should I try to create a subset using "Planned end date" wherein the records which have Planned end date more than 4 days from today's date should be in a different subset?